How to add injectable data to Angular from server-side rendering
I'm building ASP.NET SPA application with Angular. I needed some Open Graph protocol meta tags to be updated from server, and created this workaround  for that. The only problem comes with duplicate queries on server side and client side, e.g. if you check github project mentioned there, I'm querying the same Item in server side (check SeoController)
[HttpGet("item/{id}")]
    public async Task<ContentResult> Get(int id)
    {
        **var item = await _itemsService.GetItem(id);**

        return await _seoService.SetMetasAndGetContentResult(item.Title,
            new Dictionary<HtmlMetaTagKey, string>()
            {
                {new HtmlMetaTagKey("name", "description"), item.Content},
                {new HtmlMetaTagKey("name", "keywords"), $"buy in USA {item.Title}"},
                {new HtmlMetaTagKey("property", "og:image"), item.ImagePath},
            });
    }

And once the angular scripts gets loaded, same I'm doing using httpclient from client side, requesting data from ItemsController
[HttpGet("item/{id}")]
    public async Task<ContentResult> Get(int id)
    {
        **var item = await _itemsService.GetItem(id);**

        return await _seoService.SetMetasAndGetContentResult(item.Title,
            new Dictionary<HtmlMetaTagKey, string>()
            {
                {new HtmlMetaTagKey("name", "description"), item.Content},
                {new HtmlMetaTagKey("name", "keywords"), $"buy in USA {item.Title}"},
                {new HtmlMetaTagKey("property", "og:image"), item.ImagePath},
            });
    }

In Angular's items.component.ts
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.getAndUpdateItem();
    });
  }

  private getAndUpdateItem() {
    **this.itemsService.getItem(this.id)**.subscribe({
      next: (value: Item) => {
        this.item = value;
        this.titleService.setTitle(this.item.title);

        this.metaService.updateTag({
          property: 'title',
          content: this.item.title,
        });
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error(err.error);
      },
    });
  }

So what I need, is to eliminate second call from client side, I'm trying append a script element into HTML body from the server side, using AngleSharp DOM manipulations, and make data injectable on client side. From Angular side there's providers, where I can add any data like this
providers: [
    AuthGuard,
........
    { provide: "TENANT", useValue: getTenant() },
  ]

And that data is injectable in any service like this
constructor(@Inject("TENANT") private tenant: string) {}
So.. is there any way to add script in a body from server, which is injectable in a same way?
Btw I know about SSR rendering, but for my application it is quite complicated, I'm using Angular 18 with Google material design + fxlayout, and have to add lots of client side isolation using isPlatformBrowser. For now I'm looking for quick workarounds to go with.
Described above, only Idea I have, to read main.js file, and use regex to replace the data inside main.js, but I'm hoping for more elegant and easier solution, and more performant. Also I tryed SSR rendering, but that's quite complicated.

Believe it or nor, SSR is the easiest way. Here's an example that does what you're saying. Another option is to do http calls during SSR, and store the data in the TransferState, but that's not always possible

I saw that sample, but looks like it won't work with .mjs files. I've created issue on https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices/issues/61

Ah yes I noticed. But I didn't find the time yet to investigate. I'll try and look at it tonight

Also I think mjs will never work here. The bundle must be CommonJS, so either .js or .cjs. The default export function is being invoked here by the express server

Another thing you may try is to use server side rendering by running asp.net core and the angular app side-by-side. Then you only need to run npm start on your live server

@Pieterjan
'Another thing you may try is to use server side rendering by running asp.net core and the angular app side-by-side. Then you only need to run npm start on your live server'
That is not that easy, I'm hosting my app on App Service, and only one runtime I can choose. The only option I have is to host frontend on separate appservice with node runtime, and configure backend as subdomain, as I have httponly cookies authentication, which works only on a same or sub domains.

@Pieterjan Also could you try please use just SSR for this angular material template ? https://github.com/jcphlux/angular-material-template
I tried, and there's tons of issues with it. Seems like material design only started to be supported for SSR since latest Material 18 version!
